# How to import JavaScript functions with wasm-bindgen with --target no-modules?

Tags: javascript, rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I am trying to work out how to call a JavaScript function using Rust and wasm-bindgen. Due to [lack of browser support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_statements_import_worker_support), I cannot use wasm-bindgen with ES6 modules together with a Web Worker.

As far as I can tell, declaring that a JavaScript function exists for me to call on the Rust side is straightforward

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
extern {
    fn logProgress(percent: f64);
}
```

I have no idea where to define the JavaScript implementation however. If I try to just call a Rust function from JavaScript that calls the undefined `logProgress` then I get a runtime error: `Error: logProgress is not defined`

I can see from the wasm-bindgen docs that if I was using wasm-bindgen with ES6 modules then I could change the rust code to

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen(module = "/progress.js")]
extern {
    fn logProgress(percent: f64);
}
```

and declare the JavaScript function in `progress.js`

```js
export function logProgress(percent) {
    console.log(percent)
    // actual implementation would not just log
}
```

Since I am instead importing my Rust APIs via the `wasm_bindgen` global, I presume I should be able to define the implementation somewhere around the same part in my Web Worker, but I have searched through a lot of docs and can't find anything on how to do this.

```rust
importScripts('foo_wasm.js')
wasm_bindgen('foo_wasm_bg.wasm').then(fooWasmModule => {
    memory = fooWasmModule.memory
    const { Foo, Bar, Baz, foobar } = wasm_bindgen;
    // JS has 'imported' the Rust structs and functions
    // How to 'export' the JS functions to Rust?
}
```

Comment: wasm_bindgen will be binding that import to `logProgress` in the [`WorkerGlobalScope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope) (per [`importScripts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts)—there's nothing special about bindgen here).  Either define the function in the worker's global namespace, e.g. at the same level as the `importScripts` call, or import it too from a file using another `importScripts` call (or another argument to the same call).  If you want to use a non-global namespace, set the `js_namespace`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guided by @eggyal comment. `wasm-bindgen` provides a `WorkerGlobalScope` type inside `web-sys` crate, however, you cannot use it as it will not have the functions you have defined in your own worker.

So instead what you want to do is to rely on [ducktyping](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/reference/working-with-duck-typed-interfaces.html). You define your own `WorkerGlobalScope` type and then treat imports as methods of the object.

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
extern "C" {
  type WorkerGlobalScope;

  #[wasm_bindgen(method)]
  fn logProgress(this: &WorkerGlobalScope, percent: f64);
}
```

You then make use of it like so:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn call_from_worker() {
  let global = js_sys::global().dyn_into::<WorkerGlobalScope>();
  if let Ok(worker) = global {
    worker.logProgress(99.9);
  }
}
```

The downside is that the cast will fail if you try to use it outside a worker.